# how opening the targeted activity on click of notification when app is in background

Tags: android, firebase, notifications

I have sent notification through firebase console using key vale pair and handled the notification in launcher activity. below is the tried code:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    if (intent.hasExtra("click_action")) {
        ClickActionHelper ck=new ClickActionHelper();
        ck.startActivity(intent.getStringExtra("click_action"), intent.getExtras(), this);
    }
}



 public class ClickActionHelper {
    public  void startActivity(String className, Bundle extras, Context context){
        Class cls=null;
        try {
            cls = Class.forName(className);
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){

        }
        Intent i = new Intent(context, cls);
        i.putExtras(extras);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

but this way i am not able to open the targeted activity on click of notification. Any ideas?

Comment: Read https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation.html

Comment: @Raghunandan my question is different i need to start a particular activity and that can be any activity in the app.so i need to define all the attributes given in the above link for every activity and what if i need to load fragment?

Comment: I would have type associated for each activity to open. based on that i use a switch case and navigate to that particualt activity. Fragment is hosted by a activity. So you need to start a fragment in that case

Comment: i can load fragment but issue is that i am not sure which call back method should i used and in which activity(mainActivity??) when the app is in background...i have tried above solution but that did not work for me....please give me any sample document if possible...thanks

Comment: Again read the link mentioned. If your looking for something else sorry I do not know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to navigate any Activity then there should be bind with `Notification class(NotificationCompat.Builder)` which is missing in implementation.

Below line is very important to redirect any Activity:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new **NotificationCompat.Builder(this); builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);**
```

Here `resultPendingIntent` is used for to containing the backstack for the Activity with the notifications as below:

// Gets a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack PendingIntent

```
resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

The complete code snippet is available [here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation.html).

```
int id = 1;

Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
// Adds the back stack
stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);
// Adds the Intent to the top of the stack
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
// Gets a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(id, builder.build());
```

**Edit:**

- Let me explain how it will works
- Suppose you are set response from server as below

  {
      "registration_ids": ["XXX", ...],
      "data": {
          "id_offer": "41"
      },
      "notification": {
          "title": "This is the Title",
          "text": "Hello I'm a notification",
          "icon": "ic_push",
          "click_action": "ACTIVITY_XPTO"
      }
  }

**And In your Manifest File**

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityXPTO" android:screenOrientation="sensor" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"> <intent-filter> <action android:name="ACTIVITY_XPTO" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> </intent-filter> </activity>
```

When the app is closed or in background and the user clicks on the notification it opens my `ActivityXPTO`, to retrieve the `id_offer` I only need to do:

```
public class ActivityXPTO extends AppCompatActivity { 
    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String idOffer = "";
        Intent startingIntent = getIntent();
        if (startingIntent != null) {
            idOffer = startingIntent.getStringExtra("id_offer"); 
        // Retrieve the id
        }
        getOfferDetails(id_offer);
        }
    }
}
```

**And In Second Way**

- Send key through data payload like below and get key in MainActivity via getIntent() and call specific activity or fragments.

  json1.put("title","Your Title");

  json1.put("body","body content");

  json1.put("message","Your Message");

  json1.put("screen","2"); //secondFragment is 2nd position in nav drawer

  json.put("data", json1);

Sample project on [GitHub](https://github.com/Google-IO-extended-bangkok/FCM-Android).

Comment: According to above code when user click on notification ResultActivity.class is going to open. but in my code what  i trying is sending class name in the value of key: click_action through firebase console. i want to open that particular class that is defined in the firebase console..is that possible?

Comment: I have edited the answer under the "Edit" section. Kindly go through it. Do let me know is it helpful to you or not.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing works for me. The thing work for me is simple. Make sure you add this in the activity that you want to open directly.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="MainActivity" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

And from the push notification you must add a new payload: **click_action**
it will looks like this -

```
"notification": {
  "title": "hello",
  "body": "test message",
  "click_action": "MAIN_ACTIVITY"
},
```

> Note: You can name it as you want **MAIN_ACTIVITY** but must be same in both place.