# Open New Activity When app gets the notification from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using FCM for Notification. Notification is Working good, but I want to open new Activity when the app gets the notification. Is it possible using FirebaseMessagingService?

I tried this Code

```
public class MyFirebaseMEssagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            //Call new Activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlertActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            intent.putExtra("alert", "alert");
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
}
```

it's work fine when the app is open but, if the app is not running it's not working.
I want to open an activity even the app is not running.

Comment: Then you have to use data payload instead of notification payload.

Comment: @Piyush have any reference link ?

Comment: Check [this](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options) and [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)

Comment: @Piyush I'm checking.

Comment: You can refer [ https://stackoverflow.com/a/40171353/5523949]  to open activity from FCM when app is in background.